# Random tree CvRTrees persistence issue opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement a random tree classifier using Opencv. I succeed implementing it with opencv and it is working.

Then I decided to separate the training part from the classification part.
The idea is to save the trained forest and load it back when you want to classify something.

I tried in two different way:

1. using **write and read** methods of the super class **CvStatModel**
2. using **store and load** methods of the super class **CvStatModel**

But results form the older implementation that did not save trees to file are different and worst.

Following code is the implementation of 2nd point:

To store it:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<scenes.size(); ++i) {
      char class_fname[50];
      char output[100];
      sprintf(class_fname,"class_%d.xml",i);
      sprintf(output,"class_%d",i);
      //classifiers[i]->save(class_fname,output);
      classifiers[i]->save(class_fname);
    }
```

To load them back:

```
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i<CLUSTERING_N_CENTERS;i++){
    char class_fname[50];
    char output[100];
    sprintf(class_fname,"class_%d.xml",i);
    sprintf(output,"class_%d",i);
    classifiers[i] = new CvRTrees();
    //classifiers[i]->load(class_fname,output);
    classifiers[i]->load(class_fname);
  }
```

I'm using opencv 2.4.6
Does anyone have suggestions on this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an error due to file mistake!

So the persistency is working!

But I leave the post as sample if someone needs to implement it!