# OpenCV - Export a CvRTrees object to a file?

Tags: opencv, random-forest

I was wondering if it was possible to export (write) a CvRTrees object (effectively the forest of trees) to a file, and then import that model into a different OpenCV session.

I ask as my training/test system is separate from the on-line system, and being able to move the model between the two would be a huge help.

I'm using OpenCV v 2.4.10

Thanks!!

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20380640/326849.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem and it seems that the documentation is a bit poor.
I had a look at the source code and there are two functions which should solve your problem:

void CvRTrees::write( CvFileStorage* fs, const char* name ) const

void CvRTrees::read( CvFileStorage* fs, CvFileNode* fnode )